How to separate JSON objects in PostgreSQL 8.0.2
When I run the following code
select u.user_id
,u.first_name
,u.last_name
,u.email_address
,u.zip_code
,u.birthdate
,u.gender
,qr.answer
,qr.question_id
from fancompass_acurve.users u
left join fancompass_acurve.question_responses qr
on u.user_id = qr.user_id

For the qr.answer I get results like ["1","2","3","4"],["3","4"],["1","4"]. I want to split it so I have row for each answer.
I have tried different functions like jsonb_array_elements_text or CROSS APPLY to no success, and I am not sure if it is because my version of PostgreSQL or not.

Are you sure you want to use PostgreSQL 8.0.2? That version reached end of life in 2010... 14 years ago. There are no security patches, no bugfixes, nothing.

@TheImpaler I don't know a whole lot about PostgreSQL 8.0.2. Doesn't that have something to do with the database itself? This is for work, and I don't have much say in that...unless it is something I can do for myself.

I think you can UNNEST function for breaking down array into rows
select 
 jq.user_id
,jq.first_name
,jq.last_name
,jq.email_address
,jq.zip_code
,jq.birthdate
,jq.gender
,answer
from (
  select u.user_id
  ,u.first_name
  ,u.last_name
  ,u.email_address
  ,u.zip_code
  ,u.birthdate
  ,u.gender
  ,qr.answer
  ,qr.question_id
  from fancompass_acurve.users u
  left join fancompass_acurve.question_responses qr
  on u.user_id = qr.user_id
) jq, unnest(jq.answer) as answer

